# Iptables Allow MYSQL server incoming requests

Tags: mysql, iptables, centos6, mediawiki

I am trying to get my new MediaWiki server to allow connections to our MySql Server and right now I cannot get my iptables firewall set up right for this.

The rule I am applying is the following

```
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 129.130.155.39 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT           # MySQL
```

But my iptables log is still show that the connections can not be established and is being blocked/denied.

```
    Nov 21 09:48:39 hds-it kernel: Firewall Deny: [OUTPUT] IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=129.130.155.210 DST=129.130.155.39 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=29232 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58862 DPT=3306 SEQ=914529531 ACK=0 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03BCF2BC0000000001030307)
```

When I turn off iptables, everything works as it should including editing the wiki database.
What am I doing wrong with my rule?

Edit: here is my output from iptables -L -n -v => http://pastie.org/5413124
I could not get it to format right here.

Comment: 129.130.155.39 is mysql server?

Comment: Please post other rules as well (``iptables -L -n -v``). The order of rules in the chains *do* matter. Therefore, it might be blocked by a rule earlier in the chain.

Comment: Yes 129.130.155.39 is the MySql server. Here is the iptable -L -n v http://pastie.org/5413124

Answer (score 1):

From your log entry, this appears to be outgoing traffic, not incoming. You need to place the rule in the `OUTPUT` chain, not the `INPUT` chain.

Comment: I did do this and it still did not make a difference. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was going on. I accidentally switch two numbers around in one of my rules in the IP and that was was not allowing it to work. So I had 192 instead of 129... Sorry. Thank!